# How to configure lint by gradle options from command line?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Is there any way to set `abortOnError false` for lint by command line options of gradle/gradlew, without gradle config changing?

Answer (score 3):

There may be a more direct way to do this, but I recently solved this problem by setting `abortOnError` based on a project property that can be overwritten from the command line.

Something like this:

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError project.hasProperty("abortOnLintError") ? project.getProperty("abortOnLintError").toBoolean() : false
}
```

By default, `abortOnError` is set to false, but if you want to overwrite it to true from the command line, you can:

```
./gradlew lintDebug -PabortOnLintError=true
```